# How to configure a domain with a Windows 10 Machine in Virtualbox

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, security

So recently, I had been trying to simulate attacks from [this](https://github.com/center-for-threat-informed-defense/adversary_emulation_library) github security library (I was trying to specifically emulate the carbanak attack) by hosting multiple VMs on my laptop (I was using host only network if that helps).

However, I encoutered some issues in my carbanak attack, specifically, on step 4.4, I got the following error: `ERROR: Exception calling "GetCurrentDomain" with "0" argument(s): "Current security context is not associated with an Active Directory domain or forest."`. I understand that means that my VM was wasn't connected to a specific Active Domain.

So I setup a Windows Server 2019 VM that acted like a domain controller, and I setup that VM, and proceeded to connect my Windows 10 VM to the Windows Server VM with the domain name `cherry.com` and create a new user, that I connect to my Windows 10 VM (using Windows + I and the clicking on Access Work or School, and then following), and I'm fairly sure that my machine is connected to the Server.

However, whenever, I type this `[System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain]::GetCurrentDomain()` in Powershell as Admin (which is what caused the original error), I get the following error: `ERROR: Exception calling "GetCurrentDomain" with "0" argument(s): "The server is not operational.".

How would I make my server operational?

Thank you

Comment: Looks like you didn't actually join the computer to the domain.  You can check for sure with this PowerShell command: `(Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Computersystem).PartOfDomain`

Comment: @heavyd I tried that command within powershell, and it returned True.

Comment: Also, @John, I was trying this under Host Only (wanted to avoid internet access because that would allow me greater flexibility with IP addresses and such

Comment: Is there no way to keep this setup isolated? Do I need to use bridged in order to use the DC server?

Also, would just switching from Host Only to Bridged work in that case? I'm asking because neither of my VMs are connected to the internet, and I now get `ERROR: Exception calling "GetCurrentDomain" with "0" argument(s): "Current security context is not associated with an Active Directory domain or forest."` this error message again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148177/discussion-between-saurav-chittal-and-john).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, is the domain you set up actually cherry.com?
IF so this is an existing domain been around since 95, and could be part of the problem. You would have to make sure no computer could resolve cherry.com without going through your domain controller, and making sure IT does not allow  outside queried for such. IF this is just labs, it is best to stick with .local domains to avoid all of this. Production networks have largely moved off .local, but in local labs, still pretty common.

second would be do the clients connecting show your DC as their primary DNS? There are many resource records that will be required for AD to function correctly, and it is found through that DNS server. This is why AD HAS to have DNS to function properly.

If those do not address the issue, let me know, and I will edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: About the cherry.com being an existing domain, I understand it would be an issue, however, I'm using this in Host-Only Network, which means that there is no internet access for both my VMs. I assumed that because I was not exposing it to internet, any domain name would be fine.

For the primary DNS question, when I type `ifconfig /all` in powershell, I get the primary DNS suffix to be `cherry.com` which means and I assume that DC is connected to my main Windows 10 VM, and the primary DNS is correct.

Comment: I mean the DNS server in ipconfig, is it set to the IP address of the AD controller itself?

Comment: If I type `ipconfig`, I get nothing in regards to the DNS Server. However, the `DNS Servers` fields in `ipconfig /all` are the correct IPs for the Server. Although the thing is that, I manually added the said IP Address and Default DNS gateway and they are both shown, hence I'm confused about whether they are from the DNS Server or whether it was what I wrote

Comment: DNS servers are not assigned by the DNS server, they are part of a static IP address assignment (Manually typed), or delivered by DHCP. You are logged in as a user *of* that domain correct?

Comment: I am yes, when I connected to the domain, the username and password of the Win10 User changed to match the User within the server

Comment: Although I am not convinced this is what t is, I would try to see if in powershell "Reset-ComputerMachinePassword -Server {Your Ad Controller} -Credential {Domain Admin Credentials}" If that does not work or lead to some new revelation, I would disjoinn the computer form domain, delete referenced from ADUC, and rejoin.

Comment: That worked!! Thank you so much for your help. Do you know what was causing the issue?

Comment: Excellent! Which part, the powershell command or the dis/rejoin?
Domain rejoin could have been  thousand things, and whichever one it was got fixed by the full reset. If it was the powershell, then it has lost the computer password, essentially how the computer communicates in the background to provide the channels by which the other things work. That's why I asked if you were logged in as domain account. Because it seemed like an authentication issue. How it was lost could be a myriad of things. But if it happens again yo know what to do!

Comment: Ah my apologies for the late reply but thank you so much again, that helps me immensly